# Meaning of "Flighten"

Tags: meaning

This word doesn't really exist, but I wonder what do you think about it at first glimpse?

Jordan appeared to have shirts named "Flighten up": [http://www.amazon.com/Jordan-Flighten-Basketball-Jersey-Shirt/dp/B00GBA7ZC4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GBA7ZC4). What's the feeling it gives you in this context? Something like "Fly up", "Light weight"?

What's your general feeling about this word? Do you feel it's a positive word as it reminds you words/phrases like "enlighten", "lighten up", or a negative one as it might sound like "frighten"?

Comment: My feeling is it is a good [portmanteau](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/portmanteau).

Comment: @Rathony perhaps something like flight + lighten, or fly + enlighten?

Comment: I think it's stupid.  The coiner might get a job naming new medicines for big pharma.

Comment: @TimRomano perhaps that's why it seems that the Jordan shirts now are just called "Flight"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uN7vm-k-AaA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word gets a number of hits on Google (not all related to Michael Jordan's clothing line), so in a sense it does exist.

The logo on Michael Jordan's "Flighten Up" line is a basketball player aloft holding a ball.

[image]

"Lighten up" is a common idiom said when encouraging someone to worry less, become more cheerful, less sad or discouraged, like lifting the spirits or mood.

Michael Jordan was one of the best basketball players ever to play the game. He had one of the (if not *the*) highest vertical leaps (almost 48 inches). That's just about like flying to the mere mortals watching the game. That's a lot of "air" beneath him.

In keeping with "Air Jordan" sneakers (a Nike line designed and named for him), intimating that wearing the sneakers might give you a bit of the vertical jump he could achieve (or not), his "Flighten up" is also a play on that concept.

I'm not sure it has anything to do with enlightenment. Just a play on words, and his brand may well not have been the first to make that portmanteau.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think it's okay to interpret "Flighten" as a positive portmanteau that associates with cheerfulness and encouragement in general, or it's more appropriate to be *only* used in a more specific context such as sports or maybe aeronautics? I feel the former might have gone too far.

Comment: There is nothing that has a negative connotation here, and others have used it outside of the clothing line, so, yes. :)